# The age of terror is an age of shocks. What is a difference between "the+noun+of" and "a+noun+of"?

Tags: nouns, prepositions

I thought when a noun followed by "of something" has to be addressed with "the" because it is subject to the following of... However, I found the sentence such as "The age of terror is an age of shocks." Should be it like "The age of terror is the age of shocks"? Please give me some advice.

Comment: Please provide a link to the source of the quotation, so that answers can refer to the appropriate context.